# Getting Error during while porting code from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, exception

I am trying to move my old project code from eclipse to Android Studio , well I have been successful , I am facing an issue for this project .
Below is my gradle file .

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourcompany.yourprojectname"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 16
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    implementation files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpmime.jar')
    implementation files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.6.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/java-json.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jsoup-1.8.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jxl-2.6.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    implementation files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/ViewHelperLib.jar')
}
```

​

And I am getting below Exception 
I think it mainly due to libraries and few other tweaking of code in gradle will do the thing .

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at
```

**EDIT :**

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.appname"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="24"
    android:versionName="5.1.7" ><!-- live on store 18th apr 18 -->

<!-- android:targetSdkVersion="22" -->
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16"
         />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.company.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.company.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
```

Comment: can you post your manifest file

Comment: can you please tell me how moved your eclipse project to android studio ? and also tell me the android studio version.

Comment: You can try to use gradle instead of using `.jar`. Many of your libraries' you can find gradle. from net. And its also better to use. All the best :)

Comment: @vm345 : Please check edit for Manifest file

Comment: @Yatin in your manifest file there are many duplicate permissions. That may be the reason

Answer (score -1):

change `applicationId "app id"` to `applicationId "com.yourcompany.yourprojectname"`

applicationId will override the packageName defined in manifest. And, It is not allowed the name with a blank.

Comment: i know that it was only that to protect the identity